# Remove startup password when default login is command line

Tags: boot, command-line, login, password, auto-login

When I boot up my computer, it goes straight to the command line.  I modified `/etc/default/grub` file from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `quiet splash text`.

Can someone please explain how to set auto-login when I boot into the command line?  All I have found is `sudo visudo` which completely removes the sudo password which is not what I want.

Setting auto login from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is auto login for the gui only.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To autologin Ubuntu, you can modify the following file `/etc/init/tty1.conf` to below:

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
    not-container or
    container CONTAINER=lxc or
    container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -n -l /bin/su -o '- root' -8 38400 tty1
```

If you want to understand what the script means, see `man init`.

This logs in as root! replace `'- root'` with `'- user'` where `user` is the user you want to log in as